# cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I got below error message when I run `model_main_tf2.py` on Object Detection API:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 36, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import lvis_evaluation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/metrics/lvis_evaluation.py", line 23, in <module>
    from lvis import results as lvis_results
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/lvis/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lvis.vis import LVISVis
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/lvis/vis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import _registerMatType
ImportError: cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

The weird thing is I run the same code before, it worked well but now it gives me an error.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The same thing occurred to me yesterday when I used Colab. A possible reason may be that the version of opencv-python(4.1.2.30) does not match opencv-python-headless(4.5.5.62). Or the latest version 4.5.5 may have something wrong...

I uninstalled opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 and installed 4.1.2.30 and it fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Asaka!! It worked after installing `opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30` on colab.

Comment: @Asaka - How did you find out which library was the culprit and which version is the correct one?  I have no clue when I get this kind of incompatibility error.  Why Colab is not doing a good job with this production compatibility issue?

Comment: @Nguaial-Actually I just use `!pip list` to check the version of open-cv related packages, and I see the version opencv-python-headless does not match with others. 
Besides, I once got to know that   '_registerMatType' is a new module introduced after 4.5.4, so I think maybe it is the answer.

Answer (score 34):

The same thing occurred to me. My status:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip list |findstr opencv
opencv-python                 4.5.2.52
opencv-python-headless        4.5.5.62
```

The version isn't same. So I first uninstall headless:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62
```

Then reinstall headless 4.5.2.52 with opencv-python package.

```
pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.2.52
```

The problem is the resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking for this

Answer (score 11):

Try uninstall and install(version 4.1.2.30) Headless main modules package

`!pip uninstall opencv-python-headless`
`!pip install opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30`

Comment: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30`

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue and the problem was with opencv versioning:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip list |findstr opencv
opencv-python                 4.5.2.52
opencv-python-headless        4.5.5.62
```

As you can see the versions are not the same, so first uninstall headless:

`pip uninstall opencv-python==4.5.2.52`

And then reinstall opencv-python 4.5.5.62 with opencv-python package:

`pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by just uninstalling and reinstalling opencv.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 3):

After I updated opencv this error occured, in my case

```
pip list | grep opencv
```

showed:

```
opencv-contrib-python    4.5.3.56
opencv-python            4.5.5.62
```

I upgraded opencv-contrib-python

```
python -m pip install --upgrade opencv-contrib-python
```

and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this issue on docker: I was trying to use version `4.3.0.38` and I couldn't find any pre-installed OpenCV on the docker image I was working with. Installing the package with `conda install -c conda-forge opencv=4.3.0` instead of `pip` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following method was a solution.

> pip list | findstr opencv
> opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.64
> opencv-python         4.5.3.56

I installed opencv earlier than opencv contribution.
So, I decided to make their versions the same.

> pip uninstall opencv-python==4.5.3.56
> pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64

The problem was gone.
Thanks.