# cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I got below error message when I run some codes according to Google Colab:'cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)'. And I tried to uninstall the opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 and installing opencv 4.1.2.30 using the following lines:'!pip uninstall opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 !pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30 'but it seemed that the new version wasn't installed because it then said'no module named cv2'. How should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: you expect a non-headless variant to work on colab? a variant of version 4.1 that is rather ancient? how about 4.5.4?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It's the non-headless problem and I installed the headless version and it finally works!

Comment: please check the right answer in the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537488/cannot-import-name-registermattype-from-cv2-cv2

Answer (score 2):

```
!pip uninstall opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 
!pip install opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30
```

worked for me