# Something wrong occurred when I import cv2

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

How this occurred: I wrote `import cv2` in jupyter notebook code cell and run,then `ImportError` occurred.

What I have tried: I have tried to uninstall `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python`
and reinstall `opencv-python`, but it didn't work.

Detailed Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7660ed0d4d71> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import os
      4 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      5 import time

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from .cv2 import *
----> 9 from .cv2 import _registerMatType
     10 from . import mat_wrapper
     11 from . import gapi

ImportError: cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2\cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd)
```

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70537488/1025391

Comment: make sure you use official packages from pypi, **not from conda**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have reinstalled `opencv-python`, I believe you have the latest version, `4.5.5.62`.

Simply make sure that you have the corresponding version of `opencv-python-headless`, which is also the latest version, `4.5.5.62`. If your `opencv-python-headless` is not the latest version, I recommend you uninstalling it, and then reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I created an environment named tf1 in conda before, and I tried to reinstall opencv-python and opencv-python-headless many times. I also checked the version problems between them, and there was no problem.
My problem occurred in jupyter notebook. Although I have modified it to use the tf1 kernel, the kernel in the notebook is still used by the system, so I directly use pip list in cmd to check the version, and finally found The versions of opencv-python and opencv-python-headless of the system do not correspond, and they work normally after the last update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).