# cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' The other solutions don't work

Tags: python

I have been trying to run a script for object detection and I keep getting the following error,I have seen the same question being answered but I didn't get the desired result while reinstalling open cv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 36, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import lvis_evaluation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/metrics/lvis_evaluation.py", line 23, in <module>
    from lvis import results as lvis_results
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/lvis/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lvis.vis import LVISVis
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/lvis/vis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import _registerMatType
ImportError: cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name '\_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537488/cannot-import-name-registermattype-from-cv2-cv2)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing occurred to me then i update my all opencv modules:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip list |findstr opencv
opencv-contrib-python         4.5.3.56
opencv-python                 4.5.2.52
opencv-python-headless        4.5.5.62
```

The version isn't same. So I first uninstall all opencv modules:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

Then reinstall all opencv modules in 4.5.5.62 version.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.62
pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.62
```

The problem is the resolved.