# Having trouble importing cv2, outputting an importerror

Tags: python, opencv

**Input**

Trying to import these libraries and `cv2` is throwing an error:

```
import argparse
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import keyboard as key
import imutils
import mediapip as mp
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import sys
import time
```

This is the error returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ee20a49702d1> in <module>
      1 import argparse
----> 2 import cv2
      3 from datetime import datetime
      4 import keyboard as key
      5 import imutils

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from .cv2 import *
----> 9 from .cv2 import _registerMatType
     10 from . import mat_wrapper
     11 from . import gapi

ImportError: cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (/Users/ryleigh_grove/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70537488/cannot-import-name-registermattype-from-cv2-cv2

Comment: for future reference I'd recommend checking out a tool called Conda/Anaconda. Its a python package installation tool similar to pip that handles package version conflicts that can sometime cause odd issues like this.

Comment: OP is using anaconda already. I doubt recommending more of the same will solve the problem.